# Redirect named pipe input to file

Tags: bash, shell, named-pipes

I would like to create a file to which I can write as described in the [Datadog Datagram docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/datagram_shell/):

```
echo -n 'a' >/dev/udp/localhost/8125
echo -n 'b' >/dev/udp/localhost/8125
echo -n 'c' >/dev/udp/localhost/8125
```

Everything that is written to that file should be – instead of being handled by Datadog and sent to them via the agent – written to a log file. After executing the three lines above the log file should contain the following:

```
a
b
c
```

I thought that a named pipe and a background process that handles that would be perfect. However, it does not work as expected and the background process never writes anything, even though writing seems to work.

I created the following script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeuo pipefail

log=/var/log/datadog-agent.log
touch $log

# https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/datagram_shell/
pipe=/dev/udp/localhost/8125
if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
    rm -f $pipe
    mkdir -p "$(dirname $pipe)"
    mkfifo -m 0666 $pipe
fi
trap 'rm -f $pipe' EXIT

while :; do
    read -r line <$pipe
    echo "$line" >>$log
done
```

And the following systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fake Datadog Agent

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/datadog-agent
Type=exec

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is started correctly after executing `systemctl enable --now datadog-agent`, however, as I said, nothing is ever being written to the log file.

This is very strange to me because opening two shell instances where I write the following in the first shell:

```sh
mkfifo pipe
while :; do read -r line <pipe; echo "$line"; done
```

And then start sending data in the second shell prints the lines correctly.

Comment: `mkfifo -m 0666 /dev/udp/localhost/8125` - what do you expect would happen here? The `/dev/udp/*` is not a file, not a fifo, it's a special file specially handled. If you create your own fifo in `/dev/udp` it is no longer handled, you are just writing to a fifo.

Comment: If you use `echo -n`, why do you expect newlines in the output?  Is a reader supposed to somehow detect boundaries between writes?

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't think the kernel knows about /dev/udp and /dev/tcp.  I believe these are special strings only recognized by the shell.  bash handles /dev/udp and /dev/tcp and attempts to create a socket.

Comment: `/dev/udp` does not exist on a fresh Ubuntu installation so I just create the directory and the named pipe there manually. This works as expected. I have to use `echo -n` because that is how the Datadog agent expects things. As I said, the read loop works fine and detects the boundaries if one is not sending things too fast (which is not the case in my scenario so should not be a problem).

Comment: You do not want to attempt to create a fifo in /dev/udp/localhost.

Comment: All of this is done in a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 Vagrant box for testing purposes. This is not a real computer. ;)

Comment: bash treats the path `/dev/udp/...` in a special way.  If you create a fifo in /dev/udp/localhost, bash is probably never even looking at it.  Instead of looking for an actual file in /dev/udp, bash just attempts to open a socket.

Comment: This datadog program reads from a **udp socket**, not a pipe or file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell that would explain the behavior I'm witnessing and answer the question.

@Shawn this doesn't matter for me because I only want to capture `echo -n` data.

Comment: So basically you want a fifo, that you can write to, and it sends the the data as udp packet to localhost to port 8125? This looks like a job for `socat`. Or the other way round? You want to start listening on localhost on port 8125 and capture all the packets that should go to datadog? Ach! Ok.

Comment: I want to capture anything echoed to that particular path into a file with a line feed inserted.

Comment: Looking at bash sources, I believe you would have to [patch bash to do that](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/redir.c#L537). Looks like bash [redirects](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/redir.c#L664) the path no matter what. Without changing the writing side I think there is nothing you can do, something like `echo 123 | tee /dev/udp/localhost/8125` may work.

Comment: Running a UDP server myself should do the trick, no? `socat udp-listen:8125 stdout` captures the very first echo but then stops… maybe I can figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: `socat -u -v -x udp-listen:8125,fork /dev/null &>/var/log/datadog-agent.log` works, it adds more decoration than the line feed but that is fine. First to summarize the findings from the comments that answer the question gets the accepted. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is found in the comments to it. Hence, this question should not go unanswered.

The code from the question works as expected, however, the path where the named pipe resides is a special path and this is the reason why the data that is being sent to it never reaches the script. The corresponding special casing in Bash for instance can be found in [`redir.c`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d894cfd104086ddf68c286e67a5fb2e02eb43b7b/redir.c#L537).

The solution to the problem is to use a real UDP server on that port:

```
socat -u -v -x udp-listen:8125,fork /dev/null &>/var/log/datadog-agent.log
```